# How to note a defaulting value in a Sequence Diagram?

Tags: uml

If an Actor does not enter a date, the date will default to today. Else the entered date will be saved.

How to, in the sequence diagram, note that the date will default if a date is not entered?

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply attach a note *"Defaults to today"* to the message and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, would you use a Self note for something like this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with a "Self note". Can you elaborate?